# default parameter for collection

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I created a parameter whose type is "Collection" and it is a multi select parameter. I want to choose one value as default but I am unable to do so. I have tried all the options mentioned in this forum like

the default values as " new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"WhatValueUWant"})) "and  " [" "] "  but still didn't work. Can any one please help me here ?

Comment: why dont you predefine the default parameter value

Comment: I want to set a default value because whenever a user opens the application, he will select a parameter only if he needs it. Else it would be a default one

Answer (score 0):

You should use this syntax to add the default value for collection type parameters :-

```
 new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Val1","Val2", "Val3"}))
```